# Grep to select the searched-for regexp surrounded on either/both sides by a certain number of characters?

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu, grep

I'm searching a database dump that doesn't have newline delimiters anywhere; it's literally a huge, huge block of text.

Thus, since I can't use grep flags like -A, -B or -C that would separate only the needed line that contains a phrase, I would like tu surround the otput with a certain number of characters (say 20) that would give a sufficient context.

How should I proceed?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Please read my question again carefully.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW.